# Call Facebook Api from .as class

Tags: flash, facebook-graph-api, flash-cs5

please I'm trying to use the Facebook Api but i get these errors

```
D:\proyectos\pa-mago-yo\MainFBtest.as, Línea 4  1172: No se encontró la definición com.facebook.graph:Facebook.
D:\proyectos\pa-mago-yo\MainFBtest.as, Línea 3  1172: No se encontró la definición com.adobe.serialization.json:JSON.
D:\proyectos\pa-mago-yo\MainFBtest.as, Línea 65 1120: Acceso a una propiedad Facebook no definida.
```

I'm importing these libraries

```
 import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
 import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
```

and I put FacebookGraphAPI.swc in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

I had to aggre 'FacebookGraphAPI.swc' in the flash movie in the option "Configuration de ActionScript" then "ruta de biblioteca" and thats all